# PowerShell executing 2 SQL queries and adding the results together

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I need to query a table in a SQL Server database using Windows authentication.  The query needs to pull 2 values and add the results together. I have the first part. The part I'm running into a problem is executing the queries and adding the results together. Any help would be appreciated.

What I have so far:

```
    $date = Get-Date
    $d = $date.day
    $m = $date.month
    $y = $date.year

    $ServerName = "SERVERNAME"
    $DatabaseName = "DATABASENAME"

    $Table = "STATSDATA" + $m + "_" + $d + "_" + $y

    $Query1 = "SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM" + $Table + 
              "WHERE POLLID=16267 ORDER BY TTIME DESC"

    $Query2 = "SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM" + $Table + 
              "WHERE POLLID=16272 ORDER BY TTIME DESC"

    #Timeout parameters
    $QueryTimeout = 120
    $ConnectionTimeout = 30

    #Action of connecting to the Database and executing the query and 
    returning results if there were any.
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerName,$DatabaseName,$ConnectionTimeout

    $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $conn.Open()
```

Unsure about the rest of this:

```
    $cmd1 = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query1, $conn)
    $cmd2 = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query2, $conn)
    $cmd1.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout
    $cmd2.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout
    $ds1 = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $ds2 = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da1 = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd1)
    $da2 = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd2)

    [void]$da1.fill($ds1)
    [void]$da2.fill($ds2)
    $conn.Close()

    $ds.Tables
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking the answer to your question with existing code is:

```
$ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0].Val + $ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0].Val
```

The members might be `Table` and `Row` instead of `Tables` and `Rows`.  I can't remember at the moment.  My syntax might not be entirely correct, but essentially that's what you have to do.  You need to reference the first Table in the DataSet, then the first Row in the Table, and then the first Column (or Val column) in the Row.  I think you can just use the column's name.

---

However, because you're fetching exactly one column of one row with each query, you could also use the `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` function twice:

```
$cmd1=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query1,$conn)
$cmd2=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query2,$conn)
$cmd1.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$cmd2.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$val1 = $cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
$val2 = $cmd2.ExecuteScalar()
$val1 + $val2
```

---

Personally, I'd use a different query that only needs to run once to get both results:

```
$Date = Get-Date

$Query = @'
SELECT SUM(VAL) Val
FROM (
    SELECT VAL,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POLLID ORDER BY TTIME DESC) RN
    FROM STATSDATA{0:m_d_yyyy}
    WHERE POLLID IN (16267,16272)
) T
WHERE RN = 1
'@ -f $Date
```

Answer (score 1):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT SUM(VAL) AS sum_val FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM <insert table name here> WHERE POLLID=16267 ORDER BY TTIME DESC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM <insert table name here> WHERE POLLID=16272 ORDER BY TTIME DESC
) AS X
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing two queries, run only one. Assuming you have two queries:

```
 $Query1 = "SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM" + $Table + "WHERE POLLID=16267 ORDER BY TTIME DESC"
 $Query2 = "SELECT TOP 1 VAL FROM" + $Table + "WHERE POLLID=16272 ORDER BY TTIME DESC"
```

You can use following syntax:

```
$querySum = "SELECT ($Query1)+($Query2) VAL"
```

And run only `$querySum`.